# What is marked with double dollar signs in Uniface 10 and where can I find the definition for this?

Tags: uniface

I am not that familiar with Uniface 10 yet. I am currently analyzing a form. In doing so, I have seen a construct in the code that I do not understand.

Example:

```
user = $SYUSER$
```

Can anyone tell if **$SYUSER$** is used to access a custom constant and where I should look for this constant defintion in the development environment?